# Datagrid auto scroll to make last row visible

Tags: wpf, silverlight

How do you make a DataGrid always keeping the last row visible?
As in automatically scrolling to the bottom when new items are added

Comment: Only comment as have not used it in DataGrid but there is  BringIntoView method that you would call on the last row.

Comment: Yes I know I can do so in code in various ways but I was wondering if there is a setting to "auto track"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use method [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324321%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a pass DataGrid item to this method.

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="5"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}">
```

**Code:**

```
 private ObservableCollection<User> _users;


    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }

        set
        {
            _users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }
```

**Add new item to DataGrid:**

```
private void BtnAdd_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Users.Add(new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Clinton" });

    //scroll to last added item
    DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(Users[Users.Count-1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to Add items to a collection, raising property changed and MANUALLY scrolling. I was after some setting on the grid to AUTOMATICALLY do this WITHOUT writing ugly code like this.

Comment: @Magnus Ahlin: If you use for example MVVM you can create own DataGrid  and call this method inside. I think DataGrid from WPF does not have property for this purpose.

Comment: You could wrap this code into a [behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476(v=expression.40).aspx) that does that every time an item is added.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple approach using LoadingRow event:

```
void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.Row.Item);
}
```

Just remember to disable it after grid loading is finished.

Comment: "Just remember to disable it after grid loading is finished"  And how is that done?

Answer (score 1):

After already try many way,this is the best way:

```
if (datagrid.Items.Count > 0)
{
    var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(datagrid, 0) as Decorator;
    if (border != null)
    {
        var scroll = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
        if (scroll != null) scroll.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
DataGrid.SelectedIndex = DataGrid.Items.Count - 1; // If you need to select the last item
DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid.Items[DataGrid.Items.Count - 1]);
```