# Placing the last row used for adding new elements at the top of the data gris

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In the data grid control, there's an empty row at the bottom. When a user fills the cells, I can store the contents, hence creating an additional element in the database.

However, when the number of pre-existing rows grows large, the user'd have to scroll each time to access that row. Is there a smooth way to move it up to the top?

The solution I can think of is placing other controls in a panel right above the data grid. But that's more work than I'm willing to spend. Still, it'd be nice to let the users not be forced to scroll their mouses off.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21630124/5089204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the collection view returned by your `DataGrid`'s Items property implements `IEditableCollectionView` (which, in my experience, does for an editable `DataGrid`), then you should be able to use the `NewItemPlaceholderPosition` property through the explicit interface:

```cs
// Assume myDataGrid is the DataGrid control holding your results.
// You can do this inside your window/control's constructor after its
// call to InitializeComponent and after myDataGrid's ItemsSource
// property has been set.
var collView = myDataGrid.Items as IEditableCollectionView;
if( collView != null )
    collView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning
```

Comment: Is that doable using XAML as well?

Comment: @Konrad I don't believe so. The [MSDN remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491085(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `ItemCollection.IEditableCollectionView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition` property says: "This member is an explicit interface member implementation. It can be used only when the ItemCollection instance is cast to an IEditableCollectionView interface."